# Old Time Machine disk - can't restore or see files

Tags: backup, time-machine, restore

I recovered an old external hard drive that I used for Time Machine backups. Now my files look like this

TimeMachine\Name MacBook Pro.tmp\0

TimeMachine\Name MacBook Pro.tmp\1a

TimeMachine\Name MacBook Pro.tmp\1a0

TimeMachine\Name MacBook Pro.tmp\1a0b

... and so on. Is there a way to look into this Time Machine backup to recover old files?